# How to install YouTrack on web hosting and access via custom domain and other queries?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I'm very new to YouTrack and tried using it on local host under Mac OSX. My first impression on it was really stuck and can't say in words how neat and elegant was the whole user interface. I'm really loving it now and would like to adapt the UI to electrical and electronics engineering projects along with the issue tracking. So far I'm already into the play and have found plenty of useful customisable features which I can turn them into the ones relevant to engineering stuff. Now I'm moving to some intermediate skill to change the UI and got some doubts to be clarified. Here are the list of queries I've got now.

1. I'm now trying it on local host under Mac OSX and its running fine without any issues. I would like to install and do online testing like hosting it under siteground or goddady and use custom domain/sub domain to access it. I mean so that I can give my team the online access.
2. I've came across other products like team city, upsource and hub. Could you please explain in brief on each?
3. I will be using it for 8-10 users now and is there any option to purchase access to custom logo, private projects and ssl without upgrading to more users.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! 1. This tutorial will be helpful for the custom domain name: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTHB/Configuring+Custom+Domain+Name .2. Hub allows you to manage users, groups and permissions across all JetBrains team tools. Upsource is basically a code review tool and Teamcity is a continuous integration build server. 3. If you want to use InCloud YouTrack, you can purchase license for 10 users only, if you're using standalone, the minimum amount of users is 25. https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy

Comment: @Kootli Thank you for the link. It's got nice guide. I don't see standalone licence starting from 25 users, you can check as both got 10 users for free.

Comment: 10 users are for free for both stand-alone and InCLoud YouTrack, but you can get custom logo and private projects only for paid YouTrack: https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy/#edition=stand-alone .